# How can I target an index in this array?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to add rename and delete functionality to my map, but I have thus far been unable to target a single value in the markers array. I tried using markers.indexOf(marker) as seen below:

```
L.DomEvent.on(deleteBtn, 'click', function(ev) {
        var index =  markers.indexOf(marker);
          console.log(marker.indexOf(index));
           console.log('Delete button clicked!');
        }, this);
        });
```

When I do this, I get all markers on the map in console. When I use the array.find method, I get back false indicating the value doesn't exist, but each marker is an object stored in local storage.The objective is to be able to retrieve an index of a member of the markers array to grab values from local storage to change them as needed.

```
 // Creates the custom markers added by the user and stores them to localStorage
    var markers = [];
    var customLayer = new L.layerGroup();
    myMap.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
          var marker = L.marker(e.latlng,
          {icon : flagIcon}).addTo(customLayer).addTo(myMap);
          marker.bindTooltip("<b>Custom</b>", {permanent: true, offset: [0, 0],direction: "bottom"});
          customLayer.addTo(myMap);
          markers.push({ coords: e.latlng, name: "<b>Custom</b>" });

          marker.on('click', function(e) {

            renameDeleteChoice(e);
            L.DomEvent.on(renameBtn, 'click', function(ev) {

                console.log('Rename button clicked!');
            }, this);

            L.DomEvent.on(deleteBtn, 'click', function(ev) {
           // I have been trying code here
               console.log('Delete button clicked!');
            }, this);
            });

    // Save marker Coords to localStorage

          markers.forEach(function() {
            window.localStorage.setItem('customData', JSON.stringify(markers));

       });
    });
```

Did I just set this up wrong? Is my array that I push new values to supposed to have this behavior?
Here's the documentation for leaflet in case anyone needs it. I'd be happy to answer any questions for clarification.

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html

Thanks in advance for any guidance you provide.

Comment: You aren't actually adding the `marker` variable into the `markers` array, you are adding in the custom object `{ coords: e.latlng, name: "<b>Custom</b>" }`

Comment: Yea, I figured that out eventually. How do I find the index of the click event? Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a unique id to the marker variable that is also referenced in the custom object, and then find the item based off that. If the `latlng` value is unique you could do something like:

```
myMap.on('contextmenu', function(e) {
    var marker = ...;
    marker.id = e.latlng; 
    markers.push({ coords: e.latlng, name: "<b>Custom</b>" });

    marker.on('click', function(e) {
        L.DomEvent.on(deleteBtn, 'click', function(ev) {
            var markerId = marker.id;
            var markerItem = markers.find(function(m) {
                return m.coords === markerId;
            });
            // update markerItem in some way
            // alternatively, use findIndex if you really just want the index
        }, this);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I ended up using index Of, but this looks like it would work, too. I appreciate the support.